# sqlparameter c# подстановка параметра в IN()

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Есть такой код, он не работает, не приносит данные:

```
var strT = "'a','b','c'";

var selA = db.test.SqlQuery(@"SELECT *
                              FROM tblTemp t
                              WHERE t.mit IN(@strT)",
                            new SqlParameter("@strT", strT)).ToList();
```

причем так:

```
var strT = "'a','b','c'";

var selA = db.test.SqlQuery(@"SELECT *
                              FROM tblTemp t
                              WHERE t.mit IN("+strT+")").ToList();
```

да работает и приносит данные

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем проблема?

Дополнение к вопросам на мой вопрос.
Я использую EntityFramework.
Подскажите пример использования SqlParameter в EntityFramework с использованием оператора IN() с заранее не известным количеством параметров внутри IN.

Comment: в том, что ты подставляешь строку, а в in параметром надо подставить массив

Comment: SqlQuery это метод , который принимает в качестве параметра sql-выражение.

Comment: создал массив var arrT = new string[3] { "a","b","c" };
подставил 
var selA = db.test.SqlQuery(@"SELECT *
                              FROM tblTemp t
                              WHERE t.mit IN(@strT)", new SqlParameter("@strT", arrT)).ToList();

получаю ошибку 
Additional information: No mapping exists from object type System.String[] to a known managed provider native type.

Comment: `SqlQuery это метод , который принимает в качестве параметра sql-выражение.` не может быть. Но вопрос не в этом, а в том, что в .NET не существует такого метода. Вы подключили библиотеку к проекту, или NuGet пакет, или сами написали этот метод. Из воздуха он не мог появиться. Вот вас и спрашивают, к какой библиотеке принадлежит этот метод.

Comment: Database.SqlQuery()
The Database class represents the underlying database and provides various methods to deal with the database. The Database.SqlQuery() method returns a value of any type.

Comment: я честно говоря не знаю, а может он входит в пакет EntityFramework

Comment: Будьте добрыдавайте вернемся к моейпроблеме

создал массив var arrT = new string[3] { "a","b","c" }; подставил var selA = db.test.SqlQuery(@"SELECT * FROM tblTemp t WHERE t.mit IN(@strT)", new SqlParameter("@strT", arrT)).ToList(); получаю ошибку Additional information: No mapping exists from object type System.String[] to a known managed provider native type.

Comment: Если вы сами не знаете, откуда этот метод, то как посторонние люди могут это узнать? Существуют десятки библиотек для работы с БД. И во многих могут быть методы с таким названием. / Хорошо, в EF действительно есть такой метод, судя по коду вы используете именно его.

Answer (score 0):

Вы работаете с Entity Framework. Так почему бы не использовать его встроенные средства:

```
var values = new string[3] { "a", "b", "c" };

var result = db.test.Where(t => values.Contains(t.mit));
```

Это запрос сгенерирует sql содержащий клаузу `in`.
Учтите, что тип массива должен совпадать с типом `mit`.

---

Вот пример использования сырого sql:

```
var values = new string[] { "a", "b", "c" };

var parameters = string.Join(", ", values.Select((_, i) => "@p" + i));

var sql = "SELECT * FROM tblTemp WHERE mit IN(" + parameters + ")";

var result = db.test.SqlQuery(sql, values);
```

Однако, непонятно, почему вы вызываете его на таблице `test`, а в запросе фигурирует `tblTemp`. Маппинг сделан? Или это очередная ошибка?

Comment: Или это очередная ошибка? - это опечатка, select на много больше и сложнее, поэтомы не использую встроенные средства

я хотел использовать SqlParameter от иньекции, а вы этот метод не используете, почему?

Comment: @Борис - что значит не использую? В приведённом коде используются параметры. Читайте документацию по методу SqlQuery. В конце концов, включите логирование и посмотрите, какой запрос уйдёт в базу.

Comment: @Борис - явно задавать именно `SqlParameter` следует в том случае, если нужно указать тип. Возможно, вам это нужно сделать. Но вы же упорно молчите и не приводите ни схему своей БД, ни описание контекста. ЗЫ: по всему интернету в тысячах ответов на форумах и в статьяъх/блогах пихают SqlParameter отнюдь не потому, что только так надо, а по незнанию чаще всего.

Comment: @Борис - _поэтомы не использую встроенные средства_ - тогда на кой чёрт вы вообще заюзали EF?

Comment: Да потому что не знаю ASP.NET только месяц как занялся MVC и про Entity Framework узнал раньше чем про DAPPER, и теперь хочу довести до логического конца и доделать с EF . Про  SqlParameter понял. Спасибо !!!!!!